# In Finder.php line 590: The "" directory does not exit. After running php artisan optimize:clear in production

Tags: laravel-7

after running **php artisan optimize:clear** my site stopped working.

I tried to do **composer dump-autoload** but still the error comes.
Help me solve this. the site is running on hostinger.com

[The output of php artisan optimize:clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb18z.png)

Comment: any luck at your end with this situation? I also got this error

Answer (score 5):

Not sure, but maybe it will be useful: I had this error after I accidentally deleted the `config` folder. After restoring the folder, everything became ok.

Comment: In my case the config directory was missing from the repository due to .gitignore file.

Answer (score 0):

You must have deleted the config file.

The same happened to me, just bring it back, and it will work.